# Passing data between controllers ASP.net API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I'm trying pass user data from one controller to another. I've been reading a lot about it here ---> http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/F2aL081113-Passing-multiple-complex-type-parameters-to-ASP.NET-Web-API.html and this guy seems to be doing exactly what I want to do, and he's using .PostAsJsonAsync to do it.

This is controller 1, which takes in user data and basically re-routes it to the other controller for authentication.

```
 public ActionResult IDB(IDBUser i)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64819");
        HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Participant/Authenticate", i).Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else { // hits this breakpoint with 500 server error 
            return View("Index");

        }

    }

}
```

}

This seems to successfully make it to the other controller (below), as I'm getting a 500 error. However, I've got a breakpoint right at the beginning of the method, and it never seems to hit it.

```
    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("Authenticate")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(IDBUser u)
    { //breakpoint it neve hits is on this line
       bool Authenticate = false;

        CredentialTester ct = new CredentialTester(u.password, u.username);
        bool isAuthenticatedInt = ct.IntTest();
        bool isAuthenticatedAcp = ct.AcpTest();

        if (isAuthenticatedInt == true || isAuthenticatedAcp == true)
        {
            Authenticate = true;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Authenticate);     
        }

        else Authenticate = false;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);   
    }
```

Any help is apprecitaed. Thanks everyone!

UPDATE
: I was able to look at the error and it is listed here:

{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Pragma: no-cache  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYTU4NDYxOVxEb2N1bWVudHNcYXAxMDk1MTQtcWEtYXVvdG1hdGlvblxXaVFhLlZhbC1JZFxNVkNcV2lRYS5WYWwtSWQuV2ViU2VydmljZVxXaVFhLlZhbC1JZC5XZWJTZXJ2aWNlXFdpUWEuVmFsLUlkLldlYlNlcnZpY2VcYXBpXFBhcnRpY2lwYW50XEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZQ==?=  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS  Cache-Control: no-cache  Date: Thu, 12 May 2016 17:07:39 GMT  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  Content-Length: 2307  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  Expires: -1}}

it looks like there's a problem with my Access- Control-Origin. I've put the appropriate adjustments in my web.config file (I've had a similar error before) but no luck.

Comment: Are these controllers part of the same application?  It seems kind of silly to make HTTP requests within the same application when you can just invoke the code directly.  (It's somewhat analogous to wrapping something and mailing it to yourself, then mailing a response back to yourself after you receive it.)

Comment: is `IDBUser` a `class` or `interface`

Comment: As for the 500 error, I guess you'll need to debug a bit to determine what the actual error is.  Is an exception being thrown within the API?  Configure errors to show debugging information and examine the actual response from the server to see what that information is.  The application could very well be telling you exactly what's wrong and all you need to do is look.

Comment: So the controllers are in two different projects. IDB user is a class. It contains a username (String) password (String) and an array of Account numbers (Strings []). As for the error, all I can see thus far is an internal 500, but yes I am trying to dig deeper and see what the error can tell me.

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, yes they are different applications running on the same machine

Comment: I found the error, and it pointed me in a better direction. It's listed above.